# ggplot2 data not displayed continuously?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to write a script which imports my data from a xls file into R and plots two columns with the ggplot2 library.
I am not sure but I think I encounter some problems which are related to the stringsAsFactors issue.
If I plot my data with the plot function the data is displayed correctly.
However, if plot my data with the qplot function the data is not displayed as it should be. On both axis after 1 it will continue with 10, 11, ...
My data.xls looks like this:

```
mess1   mess2
1.0     1.0
2.0     2.0
3.0     3.0
4.0     4.0
5.0     5.0
6.0     6.0
7.0     7.0
8.0     8.0
9.0     9.0
10.0    10.0
11.0    11.0
12.0    12.0
13.0    13.0
```

Here is my code:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
data <- read.xls("data.xls")
plot(data$mess1, data$mess2)
qplot(data$mess1, data$mess2)
class(data$mess1)
class(data$mess2)
```

The last two lines return "character" each.
You can find the according plots here:
[data displayed with plot function](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d0gl5ct9e7qhtrd/Rplot1.png)
[data displayed with qplot function](https://www.dropbox.com/s/df66awuworxlyj7/Rplot2.png)
Does anybody know how to do it properly?

Comment: I'd guess `data$mess1 <- as.numeric(data$mess1) ; data$mess2 <- as.numeric(data$mess2)` will solve this. Actually `ggplot` behaves as expected, I'd have to dig in why `plot` converts it to `numeric`

Comment: Seems like `xy.coords` (the function that `plot` uses to set it's coordinates converts `x` and `y` coordinates to `numeric` (`as.double`): `return(list(x = as.double(x), y = as.double(y), xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab)`